# Use await in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an exercise about using asynchronous function in JavaScript. Everything passes, except for the request that returns a number after await. How should I use await here?

```js
/**
 * TODO: implement an *async* function 'f' that returns the value of a parameter inside a Promise
 * @param {number} value, must be a number, isNaN() is useful here
 * @throws an error, if the parameter 'value' is not a number. The thrown error message must
 * be 'Parameter is not a number!'
 * @returns a new Promise, which resolves to the parameter value. returns a number after await
 */
const f = (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      return value;
    } else {
      throw "Parameter is not a number!";
    }
   })
}

/**
 * TODO: Implement an async function 'g' that calls the previously made async function 'f'.
 * With then() function g waits for the result of f and returns the natural logarithm (Math.log()) of f's value. returns a number after await
 * Handle exceptions gracefully by returning the thrown error message with catch().
 * @param {number} value
 */
const g = (value) => {
  return f(value).then(na_loga => {
    a = Math.log(value);
    return a;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err;
  })
}
```

Comment: `TODO: implement an *async* function 'f'` - your function `f` is not async.  Same with `g`.

Comment: You might want to use a `.then()` to do something with the value once the asynchronous function finally finishes. As always, rely on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for guidance on using specific JavaScript features.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Yep, you have to create an `async` function which is the one able to `await` a `Promise`. If you don't know what an `async` function is, you must read about it as part of the exercise is you knowing how it actually works.

Comment: @James They might not mean an `async` function but just an *asynchronous* function. I would suggest to get feedback from the instructor.

Comment: You also need to return the error message instead of re-throwing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `new Promise` constructor, you are supposed to call the `resolve` or `reject` callbacks:

```
const f = (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      resolve(value);
//    ^^^^^^^
    } else {
      reject(new Error("Parameter is not a number!"));
//    ^^^^^^
    }
  })
}
```

This usually happens asynchronously, e.g. after a timeout, but in your simple exercise you seem to be supposed to resolve/reject the promise immediately. The `throw` in your code did work because the `Promise` constructor handles synchronous exceptions in its executor callback by rejecting the promise.

Alternatives to implement this would be to use the static promise-creating helper methods `Promise.resolve`/`Promise.reject`:

```
const f = (value) => {
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    return Promise.resolve(value)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("Parameter is not a number!"));
  }
}
```

or an `async` function:

```
const f = async (value) => {
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    return value;
  } else {
    throw "Parameter is not a number!";
  }
}
```